# How can I set a project-specific environmental variable in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, path, environment-variables

I need to know whether there is any setting available in "visual studio project setting" to create a environment variable like thing in visual studio 2008 Express edition so that I need not to add into "system variable" for any specific project.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there most definitely is!

You can configure environment variables for the debugger for an individual project. You'll find the options in your project's Properties window (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>), under the "Debugging" category.

Fill in the "Environment" property with whatever variables you like.

The screenshot is from VS 2010, but everything looks pretty much the same in VS 2008:

[image: Look for the "Environment" property under the "Debugging" category]

You can also do this with property sheets if you're so inclined or need this for multiple projects.

Comment: Thanks Cody Gray !
But i had tried with this but It didn't worked for me.

TEST_PATH = "C:\Documents and Settings\vivek.kumar\Desktop\TestProject"

and used this variable in "Additional Include directories" as
$(TEST_PATH)/header
$(TEST_PATH)/lib/header

Is this the correct way or the purpose of this "Environment" is something else.

Comment: Those Environment variables are generated after debugging begins but before the application is started. By that time path of Working Directory is already established.

Comment: Yes, Dialecticus is correct. This is not the way to set Visual Studio variables, these are environment variables for the debugger.